# how to fix this prepend www at the beginning of my url creating error?

Tags: django, python-3.x

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^attendance/$', views.home, name='homepage'),
    url(r'^attendance/teacherlog/$', views.teareg, name="teareg"),
    url(r'login/logged', views.dash, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^mrkatt/$', views.mrkatt, name='mrkatt'),
    url(r'^attsheet/$', views.dispatt, name='dispatt'),

    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),

]
```

views.py

```
def mrkatt(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Mrkatform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("login/logged")
    else:
        form = Mrkatform()
    return render(request, "teacher/mrkatt.html", {'form': form})
```

i expect the url to be
"127.0.0.1:8000/mrkatt/"
but it gives
"http://www.127.0.0.1:8000/mrkatt/"
showing this site cant be reached error.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to `127.0.0.1:8000/mrkatt` using `ctrl+enter`? Check the "Address bar shortcuts" section here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have set `PREPEND_WWW = TRUE` in your `settings.py` file for development. Set it to `False`.

Comment: I tried it, but it is still directing to the url with www and giving the same error. Is there anything else I could fix? Thanks.

Comment: If anyone finds this, just clear your browser cache and cookies if it's giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to wwwprepend, or allowed host variable. To fix it, make sure both are defined to work with each other.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.127.0.0.1']
PREPEND_WWW = True
```

The dot at the start means any sub-domain will be allowed. That means with or without `www`. If you have `PREPEND_WWW` set to `True`, this wild card needs to be set also.